# Harmonic map and pullback metric

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, harmonic-functions

Let $\phi : M \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a harmonic map, where $M$ is a Riemannian manifold. Let us take coordinates $(u_1, u_2,..., u_n)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and express the Euclidean metric as $g = \Sigma g_{ij}du^idu^j$. Write now the symmetric bilinear form $\phi^*(g)$ on $M$.

My question is, is there a characterization of the fact that $\phi$ is harmonic in terms of the symmetric bilinear form $\phi^*(g)$? In other words, is there a necessary and/or sufficient condition on $\phi^*(g)$ such that $\phi$ is a harmonic map? Thanks!

Comment: $\phi^* g$ might not even be a metric. So $\phi$ is harmonic with respect to which metric on $M$?

Comment: @JohnMa I meant to say the symmetric bilinear form $\phi^* (g)$. I have edited the question. $\phi$ is already harmonic wrt the original metric on $M$. I am trying to see if we can read off this fact by looking at the pullback form $\phi^* (g)$.